# Python: Altering a specific position in a string

Tags: string, python-3.x, iteration

this is my first post and I appreciate the help.

I'm working on a problem in Python where I need to create a hangman program, and I've come across a point in the problem where I'm a bit stuck. I have the framework of what I want to do mapped out, but I am stuck on the syntax.

Essentially, I'm writing a function, where given a word and a list of letters, I have to return a string that shows which letters were correct guesses and which spots in the word are still blank. For example, if the secret word is 'apple', and the list of letters guessed is ['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's'], then the function should return '_ pp_ e'.

My approach to solving this problem is to create a variable for the secret word, and iterate over each letter to check if it's in the list of letters guessed. If it's in the list, the letter would stay; if not, it will be replaced with '_'. After the iteration is through, the function will return the secretWord variable.

Here's my code thus far:

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters and underscores that represents
      what letters in secretWord have been guessed so far.
    '''
    for i in secretWord:
        if i not in lettersGuessed:
            secretWord[len(i)] == '_ '
    return secretWord
```

My problem is with the third line in the function (secretWord[len(i)] == '_ '). I can't figure out how to get Python to replace the letter I want it to with '_ '. Since 'i' is a character, and not an integer, I can't say secretWord[i] = '_ '. I'll admit that I'm a bit of a beginner and manipulating strings is still difficult to me, so for someone with more experience this is probably a really easy fix.

Again, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### What you were trying to do

First of all, you're struggling because you don't know how to refer to the *index* of the letter you want to replace. When you do `for i in secretWord` indeed you don't get a variable that holds the index; in your code, your `i` variable holds the letter itself. Python provides a handy function for cases where you want to loop over some collection but you also want to keep track of the index as you're looping:

```
for i, letter in enumerate(secretWord):
    if letter not in lettersGuessed:
        # WATCH OUT: == is for comparison (is this equal to that?)
        #            = is for assignment (make this equal to that)
        secretWord[i] = '_ '
```

`enumerate` generates a list of (index, content) tuples, which you're breaking up into `i` and `letter` variables.

Now that's the code you were trying to write. Buuut...

#### ...It won't work.

### Solution

That's because strings in Python are immutable - once you create it, you can't change it. That might seem terribly forbidding, but instead you make modified copies of strings and assign them to different variables (or even the same variable that originally held a different string). You might've been doing this all along without realising. But what you definitely can't do is directly assign something different to part of an existing string.

@DannyMoshe pointed out a way you can get around this. The `replace` method gives you a copy of the string it was called on, with a find-and-replace performed on it. Now you can assign this copy to your original `secretWord` variable: `secretWord = secretWord.replace(letter, '_ ')`. Your original string is thrown away, and your `secretWord` variable now refers to the newly-generated string. (Yes, it takes a bit of practice to tell the difference between mutating and copying; and yes, it's confusing that assigning a new string to the variable *isn't* classed as mutating but assigning a new letter to an indexed position in that variable *is*.)

### An improvement

Problem is, you are repeatedly throwing away your old `secretWord`s and replacing them with copies that have progressively more '_'s in them. First of all, you might need to refer to the original `secretWord` again inside the same function (outside the function it hasn't changed - it was copied when it was passed to the function!) and so it's always a good idea to create a separate variable for this kind of thing. Call it `output` or `displayWord` or something. Second of all, all this copying and throwing away is inefficient. So to end, I'll show you a way to do it using a [**list comprehension**](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), which, if you haven't encountered it yet, is one of the most elegant features of Python, and often more efficient than its equivalent loop formulation.

```
displayWord = ''.join(letter if letter in lettersGuessed else '_ ' for letter in word)
```

That's it. You could replace `displayWord =` with `return` and have a one-line function. To be clear, the list comprehension part is `[letter if letter in lettersGuessed else '_ ' for letter in word]`, but that generates a list. To turn the list into a string you use `''.join()` (and you can drop the square brackets of the list comprehension itself, in that context).

One final thing. If `secretWord = "caligula"` and `lettersGuessed = "aei"`, `displayWord` would be `_ a_ _ _ u_ a`. Notice the misalignments for the letters where you haven't inserted a space. There's a perfect way to fix this. You're probably wondering about the weird syntax `''.join()`. What we're doing is calling the `join` method on the empty string. Whatever string we call `join` on acts as the separator between list items when gluing the list together. Thus, if we want our `displayWord` all neatly spaced, we could write:

```
# (note where I've put the space)
displayWord = ' '.join(letter if letter in lettersGuessed else '_' for letter in word)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! The idea of list comprehension blew my mind and the link you provided to help explain it was also very helpful in helping to solidify my understanding of the concept. I had briefly seen it mentioned but it hasn't been fully hashed out yet for the class I'm taking. I wonder why--it seems like it'll be extremely useful going forward.

Comment: I'm glad I managed to blow your mind! Well, a list comprehension is in some respects syntactic sugar, in that it condenses a pattern that you would commonly write as a loop. So in terms of learning progression, it's certainly good to learn the loop-based route first. On the other hand, it's more than syntactic sugar, in that under the surface it's optimised in a way a loop might not be. And it's a key feature of Pythonic style, so any class worth its salt will get round to it eventually. PS. If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it. (Click on the tick.) :)